# Which preposition to use here?"Of" or "among"?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition to use here?"Of" or "among"?
prepositions
I came across a blank in a sentence which was:

The peacock is perhaps the most beautiful _____ male birds.

What should I fill there? Of or among?

Comment: Either works. But it's very awkwardly phrased either way for other reasons. The *male* needs moved to the beginning of the sentence. Where you have it right now it sounds unintentionally funny.

Comment: You could say 'the peacock is the most beautiful male bird' which would have a similar meaning.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's is a cross-post of the identical question at [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/199035/which-preposition-to-use-hereof-or-among).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among in this case is most suitable. That's because we are comparing one bird with all other species, which surrounds the peacock amongst other birds. Its kind of centered by other birds and we want to talk about its beauty in comparison to them.

However I would add another word to make the sentence more meaningful.

The peacock is perhaps the most beautiful *among* *all* male birds.